# What is the difference between a Barkhausen-Kurz tube and a transmitting triode?

Tags: vacuum-tube

So I have 2 *transmitting triodes* in my VT collection:

1. GE GL-592 tube
2. Amperex 5868 tube

Both of these were marketed as transmitting triodes. So does a transmitting triode work as a Barkhausen oscillator? For the uninitiated, a Barkhausen oscillator is a specialized type of triode which acts as a reflex oscillator. Both the cathode and anode are held negative and the grid is held positive. I noticed that the Amperex 5868 tube is a radial beam triode with a very thick anode that completely shields the cathode. I still need to find a socket for it so I can test this effect using a DC power supply and an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 1):

They're no longer made because there are much better ways of generating high-power, high frequency RF and they're pretty much unavailable because they're no longer made.

If you're looking for some history, Google "Barkhausen-Kurz for about 30000 hits.

Comment: So in that case, is there a difference between a Barkhausen-Kurz tube and a (so-called)transmitting triode?

Comment: Yes. the difference between them  lies, simply, between the plate of the triode being able to get rid of heat better than the grid of the BK tube.